# create dict from tuple with non none value

Tags: python

I have a `tuple` with many `None` value(as printed in `ref`) in the code given below. I am creating a `dictionary` using this `ref` and `self.entries` defined elsewhere in the main code.

```
def parsing_write(self, filename):
    # print(self.booklist)
    datalist = []
    writer = BibTexWriter()
    writer.indent = '    '
    for ref in self.booklist:
        print(type(ref))
        print(ref)
        datadict = dict(zip(self.entries, ref))
        datalist.append(datadict)
        print(type(datadict))
        print(type(datalist))
        print(datalist)
```

The result of the code, as shown below obviously contains the key with None value, as(the complete output of the function):

```
<class 'tuple'>
('article', 'ebert2011', '\\textit{Ab Initio} Calculation of the Gilbert Damping Parameter via the Linear Response Formalism', 'Ebert, H. and Mankovsky, S. and K{\\"o}dderitzsch, D. and Kelly, P. J.', 'Phys. Rev. Lett.', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None)
<class 'dict'>
<class 'list'>
[{'Number': None, 'Booktitle': None, 'Crossred': None, 'author': 'Ebert, H. and Mankovsky, S. and K{\\"o}dderitzsch, D. and Kelly, P. J.', 'Series': None, 'Publishers': None, 'Organization': None, 'Address': None, 'Chapter': None, 'Note': None, 'Publisher': None, 'Annote': None, 'Month': None, 'Type': None, 'Institution': None, 'Edition': None, 'year': None, 'title': '\\textit{Ab Initio} Calculation of the Gilbert Damping Parameter via the Linear Response Formalism', 'ENTRYTYPE': 'article', 'Editor': None, 'journal': 'Phys. Rev. Lett.', 'ID': 'ebert2011', 'Page': None, 'HowPublished': None, 'Pages': None, 'School': None}]
```

But I want the dict to contain the key and value with non `None` value only.
How can I do that?

Comment: What do you want instead?

Comment: Potential dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544710/how-i-can-get-rid-of-none-values-in-dictionary

Comment: @zondo: `{'journal': 'Phys. Rev. Lett.', 'title': '\\textit{Ab Initio} Calculation of the Gilbert Damping Parameter via the Linear Response Formalism', 'ENTRYTYPE': 'article', 'ID': 'ebert2011', 'author': 'Ebert, H. and Mankovsky, S. and K{\\"o}dderitzsch, D. and Kelly, P. J.'}`, presumably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a generator comprehension to filter out the values which are `None`:

```
datadict = dict((k, v) for k, v in zip(self.entries, ref) if v is not None)
```

You can also use a dict comprehension in 2.7+:

```
datadict = {k: v for k, v in zip(self.entries, ref) if v is not None}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a dict comprehension to filter those values:

```
datadict = {k: v for k, v in zip(self.entries, ref) if v is not None}
```

See the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for more information on how comprehensions work.