# Optional parameters in python dict

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a way to include optional parameters into Python dictionary?

For example, I have the following return statements for get requests. They are dependent on the input and mostly identical.

If the region is passed as an input parameter, we have:

```
if region:
    return {
        'success': True,
        'result': {
            'country': country,
            'region': region, #  optional region param
            'cities': cities
        }
    }
```

If the city is passed:

```
if city:
    return {
        'success': True,
        'result': {
            'country': country,
            'city': city, #  optional city param
            'cities': cities
        }
    }
```

If nor city or region are passed:

```
return {
    'success': True,
    'result': {
        'country': country,
        'cities': cities
    }
}
```

What I want is to have one return statement:

```
return {
    'success': True,
    'result': {
        'country': country,
        if region: 'region': region, #  I know this and the next lines don't work
        if city: 'city': city,
        'cities': cities
    }
}
```

Comment: You can pass all keys to dict then filter keys with `None` value. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2544761/5741172) how to filter dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Control statement is not allowed with dict literal, but it is trivial to do this:

```
r = {
    'country': country,
    'cities': cities
}

if region: 
    r['region'] = region
if city: 
    r['city'] = city

return {
    'success': True,
    'result': r
}
```

Answer (score -1):

### Option 1

As mentioned in other answers, create a dictionary locally, and add optional parameters along the way.

### Option 2

When using the dictionary returned from your function, use

`retdict.get('city', 'defaultvalue')` instead of `retdict['city']` to make sure your don't fail on trying to get a non-existent parameter.

### Option 3

Use `defaultdict`. Some easy-to-understand examples are listed in the [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and [here](https://www.accelebrate.com/blog/using-defaultdict-python/)