# dataclasses: how to ignore default values using asdict()?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I would like to ignore the default values after calling asdict()

```
@dataclass
class A:
    a: str
    b: bool = True
```

so if I call

```
a = A("1")
result = asdict(a, ignore_default=True) 
assert {"a": "1"} == result  # the "b": True should be deleted
```

Comment: It's not possible. There is no difference between `a = A(1)` and `b = A(1, True)`

Comment: I would like asdict to return a dictionary without the default value

Comment: Similar question: [python - dataclasses: how to ignore None values using asdict()? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56839030/dataclasses-how-to-ignore-none-values-using-asdict)

Comment: For immutable types this is not too hard, but otherwise it can be hard to distinguish between `b = []; a = A(b)` and `a = A([])` (in both cases the member is `[]` but in the first case it's "important" as it shares the reference with the `b` object outside). If you don't care about this case then you can adapt some code from the question above.

Comment: Do you need to distinguish the cases `A(1)` and `A(1, True)` as mentioned above? If yes you can hook into `__init__` function of `A` to record the type. Otherwise if you can modify the dataclass type creation then just use `exclude` metadata, else modify the `asdict` function but if the default is something like `default_factory([])` there would be a problem as mentioned above.

Comment: The default value is a property of the class itself (more specifically, of the `__init__` method generated by the class), not an instance of the class initialized by `__init__`. You might want `b` to have type `Optional[Bool]`, then define your own method that will use the value of `b` to determine if the resulting `dict` should have a `b` key or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dataclasses` module doesn't appear to have support for detecting default values in `asdict()`, however the [`dataclass-wizard`](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/) library does -- via `skip_defaults` argument.

Example:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclass_wizard import asdict

@dataclass
class A:
    a: str
    b: bool = True

a = A("1")
result = asdict(a, skip_defaults=True)
assert {"a": "1"} == result  # the "b": True should be deleted
```

Further, results show it is close to *2x* faster than an approach with `dataclasses.adict()`.
I've added benchmark code I used for testing below.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict as asdict_orig, MISSING
from timeit import timeit

from dataclass_wizard import asdict

@dataclass
class A:
    a: str
    b: bool = True


def asdict_factory(cls):
    def factory(obj: list[tuple]) -> dict:
        d = {}
        for k, v in obj:
            field_value = cls.__dataclass_fields__[k].default
            if field_value is MISSING or field_value != v:
                d[k] = v
        return d

    return factory

a = A("1")
A_fact = asdict_factory(A)

print('dataclass_wizard.asdict():  ', timeit('asdict(a, skip_defaults=True)', globals=globals()))
print('dataclasses.asdict():       ', timeit('asdict_orig(a, dict_factory=A_fact)', globals=globals()))

result1 = asdict(a, skip_defaults=True)
result2 = asdict_orig(a, dict_factory=A_fact)

assert {"a": "1"} == result1 == result2

a2 = A("1", True)
a3 = A("1", False)
assert asdict(a2, skip_defaults=True) == asdict_orig(a2, dict_factory=A_fact)
assert asdict(a3, skip_defaults=True) == asdict_orig(a3, dict_factory=A_fact)
```

---

*Disclaimer*: I am the creator and maintainer of this library.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a factory function to [`asdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict) which gives you control over what you want to return from the passed object which is basically a list of key-value pair tuples.

`dataclass` stores its fields a `__dataclass_fields__` attribute which is an instance of `Field`. If the attribute has its `default` set to an instance of [`MISSING`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.MISSING), it means it didn't has a default value, so pick it. Also if the `default` attribute is not the same as what passed in, it means user provided that parameter. The caveat here is there is no difference between non-passed parameter and the passed-parameter same as the default value:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict, MISSING


def asdict_factory(cls):
    def factory(obj: list[tuple]) -> dict:
        d = {}
        for k, v in obj:
            field_value = cls.__dataclass_fields__[k].default
            if field_value is MISSING or field_value != v:
                d[k] = v
        return d

    return factory


@dataclass
class A:
    a: str
    b: bool = True


a1 = A("1")
a2 = A("1", True)
a3 = A("1", False)
print(asdict(a1, dict_factory=asdict_factory(A)))
print(asdict(a2, dict_factory=asdict_factory(A)))
print(asdict(a3, dict_factory=asdict_factory(A)))
```

output:

```
{'a': '1'}
{'a': '1'}
{'a': '1', 'b': False}
```

Comment: what's the output for `A("1", True)`?

Comment: I got your point from your comment on the question earlier. `A("1")` and `A("1", True)` behave the same. My interpretation was that whenever OP wants to get a dict from a `dastaclass` by calling `asdict`, they want to remove any attribute that is defined with a default attribute in the "definition" of the class. I guess this would help them in serialization.

Comment: @njzk2 that should be a question posed to the OP, as it is rather unfair to ask in this scenario - as the original question just mentions that default values should be omitted in the result dict object.

Comment: oh, hold on, you might be on to something. the code doesn't give the expected result when you have a non-default value for a field with a defaut value. For example, observe what happens when we have `A("1", False)`. The value for field `b` is omitted, but ideally based on the OP's specs it would not be.

Comment: `a2 = A("2",False)` =>  `{'a': '2'}`.  So, no, *currently*, just seems to be skipping attributes which *have* a default, whether it was used or not.

Comment: @JLPeyret Oh you're right. It should be fixed by now.

Comment: ok, but there's another problem too.  I was checking out what dict_factory gets and all it is is a tuple of tuples or something like that.  No class.  So then I go look how you built your factory and you *hardcode the class*.   You'd need to memoize the factory or the like (i.e. preset the class variable).  It's not hard, no, but a factory per class is not great either.

Comment: @JLPeyret I simply wrapped it in a function to accept the type( or instance, I would then change `cls` to `cls.__class__`)

Comment: Well, anyway you got my upvote too.  Nothing wrong with using an external package, but using the built-in dataclass functionality and std lib was what was interesting to me.  Hey, we're both gonna be big boys / big gals soon now - almost at 10K rep .  BTW, the default factory is ... drumrolls ... : `dict`.  That's why there's nothing else there to see.

Comment: @JLPeyret lol :D. Yes 10k is a milestone. GL

Comment: Using private attributes from dataclasses module is not good practice. In particular, `_MISSING_TYPE` and `__dataclass_fields__` are not publicly exposed or documented, thus accessing them is not something I can honestly recommend.

Comment: @rv.kvetch Thanks. I used `MISSING` instead of `_MISSING_TYPE`. Its now public and also simpler. I have no idea why `__dataclass_fields__` is not mentioned in the document nor pep.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a stab at it relying on some introspection of `A.__init__` signature.

Using dict_factory argument [SB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74293357) with a functools.lru_cache to precompute.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
from functools import lru_cache, partial
from typing import Any

@dataclass
class A:
    a: str
    b: bool = True

def build_set(di : dict[str, Any]) -> set[tuple[str, Any]]:
    return {(k,v) for k,v in di.items()}

def get_defaults(cls_: type) -> set[tuple[str, Any]]:
    "build a set of name/value for the defaults in `__init__`"
    constructor = cls_.__init__
    anno = list(constructor.__annotations__)[:-1]
    f_def = constructor.__defaults__
    reva = reversed(anno)
    revd = reversed(f_def)
    defaults = {tu[0] : tu[1] for tu in zip(reva,revd)}
    s_defaults = build_set(defaults)
    return s_defaults

@lru_cache
def calc_asdict(cls, ignore_default=False):
    """compute the ignore dict_factory for the class"""
    print(f"***calc_asdict({cls=},{ignore_default=})***")
    if ignore_default is False:
        return asdict
    s_defaults = get_defaults(cls)

    def remove_defaults(args):
        """works by substracting sets"""
        s_non_default = set(args) - s_defaults
        return dict(s_non_default)

    return partial(asdict, dict_factory=remove_defaults)

def asdict2(obj, *, ignore_default=False, dict_factory=dict):
    """if we did get a dict_factory here it would need accomodating"""
    _asdict = calc_asdict(obj.__class__,ignore_default=ignore_default)
    return _asdict(obj)      

a1 = A("a1")
a2 = A("a2",False)
a3 = A("a3",True)

for name, v in [(name, v) for name, v in globals().items() if isinstance(v, A)]:
    print(f"{name:4.4} base=>{str(asdict(v)):30.30} / asdict2(I)=>{str(asdict2(v,ignore_default=True)):30.30} / asdict2=>{str(asdict2(v)):30.30} \n")
```

#### output:

```
***calc_asdict(cls=<class '__main__.A'>,ignore_default=True)***
***calc_asdict(cls=<class '__main__.A'>,ignore_default=False)***
a1   base=>{'a': 'a1', 'b': True}         / asdict2(I)=>{'a': 'a1'}                    / asdict2=>{'a': 'a1', 'b': True}         

a2   base=>{'a': 'a2', 'b': False}        / asdict2(I)=>{'a': 'a2', 'b': False}        / asdict2=>{'a': 'a2', 'b': False}        

a3   base=>{'a': 'a3', 'b': True}         / asdict2(I)=>{'a': 'a3'}                    / asdict2=>{'a': 'a3', 'b': True}
```

And... no, it would **not** differentiate between not-passed in defaults and defaults which happened because you called `A(a=1,b=True)`, i.e. *did* provide values which were defaults.

---

Not going to repost everything, but changing the classes to use inheritance resulted in exactly the same, correct, results.  Not too surprising as `__init__` is a *generated* method on dataclasses.

```
@dataclass
class A0:
    a: str

@dataclass
class A(A0):
    b: bool = True
```

---